# Using HTTrack to clone secure websites (https://)?

Tags: web-scraping, httrack

I'm a beginner in webscraping and cloning. I was using HTTrack to clone a website such as classcentral.com (I want to clone the website only 2 levels deep). But that website uses secure protocol i.e., https://
I am doing this as a task to convert the primary language of the website, later on using some python scripts and then hosting it on a local server offline.
Please also do suggest if there is a quicker and a better of doing this website language translation task

[httrack error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwYab.png)
I tried cloning the website using HTTrack website cloning tool available [here](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html)